# AFNetworking Background Session Configuration for iOS 8 Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, ios8, nsurlsession

I'm currently developing an iOS 8 App Extension, and am having difficulty with this one last piece. In the rest of my app, I use an AFHTTPSessionManager subclass that I instantiate like this:

```
+ (MYAPIClient *)sharedClient {
    static MYAPIClient *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[MYAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kMYBaseURL]];
        _sharedClient.requestSerializer = [[MYAPIRequestSerializer alloc] init];
        _sharedClient.responseSerializer = [[MYAPIResponseSerializer alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedClient;
}
```

When I just used this regular API client, just posting some text form a share extension worked fine, and it even works for images sometimes (usually fails though), but I know that I need to be using a background session configuration. So I made a very similar api client with a background configuration setup like this:

```
+ (MYAPIClient *)sharedBackgroundClient {
    static MYAPIClient *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"com.me.myapp.backgroundconfiguration"];
        _sharedClient = [[MYAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kMYBaseURL] sessionConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
        _sharedClient.requestSerializer = [[MYAPIRequestSerializer alloc] init];
        _sharedClient.responseSerializer = [[MYAPIResponseSerializer alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedClient;
}
```

The problem is, when I make my POST using this client, I get these erros every single time.

```
Aug 21 19:19:07 MY-iPhone Share[6290] <Notice>: Attempted to create a task in a session that has been invalidated
Aug 21 19:19:07 MY-iPhone Share[6290] <Warning>: *** Assertion failure in -[MYAPIClient setDelegate:forTask:], /Users/me/Documents/myproject/myproduct/Pods/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m:337
Aug 21 19:19:07 MY-iPhone Share[6290] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: task'
```

Any advice on how to get this to work? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html):

> If your app extension initiates a background [`NSURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLSession) task, you must also set up a shared container that both the extension and its containing app can access. Use the [`sharedContainerIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/sharedContainerIdentifier) property of the `NSURLSessionConfiguration` class to specify an identifier for the shared container so that you can access it later.

And:

> If you attempt to use create a URL session from your app extension but fail to set this property to a valid value, the URL session is invalidated upon creation.

Refer to [Sharing Data with Your Containing App](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW6) for guidance on setting up a shared container.

In your example, you'd add something like:

```
sessionConfiguration.sharedContainerIdentifier = @“com.me.myapp.containerIdentifier”;
```

You'll need one background session for the containing app and one for its extension.

Comment: Feel free to submit a bug report for better error messages. Really this should throw an exception and tell you to set the property.

Comment: can you share code how we can upload images uisng adnetworking in share photo extension

Comment: Aaron Brager: Hi I done all these thing but still image not sharing. I need to call two api for share image. In first api I upload the image and I ll got the "image path" and after that I need to send the image path in another api. Can you pls help me solve my problem.

Comment: @AaronBrager : Hi I done all these thing but still image not sharing. I need to call two api for share image. In first api I upload the image and I ll got the "image path" and after that I need to send the image path in another api. Can you pls help me solve my problem.×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Comment: If this solution doesn't resolve your issue, please post a new question

Comment: New docs URL with slightly different content: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your sharedContainerIdentifier is the same identifier as the group identifier you registered for both your host app and extension app.

```
config.sharedContainerIdentifier = @“com.mycompany.myappgroupidentifier”;
```

You can register a group identifier in Xcode capabilities project tab.

Comment: I had the same problem of the original poster and did set up App Groups for both the app and extension with the same identifier. Once I updated the Shared Container Identifier as stated, I now am getting the following error: Task: <__NSCFBackgroundDownloadTask: 0x13d61a3f0>{ taskIdentifier: 1 } completed with error: unknown error and Task: <__NSCFBackgroundDownloadTask: 0x13d61a3f0>{ taskIdentifier: 1 } completed with error: Lost connection to background transfer service

Comment: why are you using download task for sharing? I think you need an upload task

Comment: well, it's an action extension, not for sharing.

Comment: @mgcm I'm getting the same error. Do you have any solution yet?