# Upload NSURLSesssion becomes invalidated in sharing extension in ios8 with error NSURLErrorDomain Code=-995

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlerrordomain

I try to upload an image using `NSURLSession` in shared extension in **iOS 8** but have this error instantly after calling

```
[task resume]
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-995 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -995.)"
```

here is my code:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:DEFAULT_SHARE_SESSION_ID];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:self.queue];
NSURLRequest *request = [self getMultipartUploadRequest:data url:url albumId:albumId];
// ... saving file here to Documents folder
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:url1];
[uploadTask resume];
```

and also I have this message in console:

```
Attempted to create a task in a session that has been invalidated
```

This code absolutely works in the app, but doesn't work in the sharing extension.
I couldn't find what does **code -995** mean.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438709/afnetworking-background-session-configuration-for-ios-8-extension

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@Wisors great! It helped, just need to set

```
sessionConfiguration.sharedContainerIdentifier = @“com.me.myapp.containerIdentifier”;
```

In my case @“com.me.myapp.containerIdentifier” was @"group.mycompany.appname" which was crucial, another identifier didn't work. 
Thank you!

Comment: i tried both "com.company.app.sharedContainer" and "group.com.company.app" which is the registered app group identifier on the developer portal but both failed with the same error!

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I was kinda stuck

Comment: I've a question for what we have to use this? "sessionConfiguration.sharedContainerIdentifier = @“com.me.myapp.containerIdentifier”;" I have already created NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier(identifier). Now when i am requesting through it (manager class) it is executing but when i try to invalidate that it throws an error. What should i do ?