# What is OSSError -995 and what do I do to fix this? (ios share extension)

Tags: ios, dropbox, ios-extensions, swiftydropbox

I extract path_lower from meta info request for a folder and feed
that into

```
client.files.listFolder(path: path, recursive: true, includeMediaInfo: true).response({ (files, error) in
```

I'm getting

```
OSError: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-995 "(null)")
```

What the heck is that and how do I go about listing shared folder contents?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the right method for listing folder contents, but it looks like you're running in to an issue because you're running inside an extension.

`NSURLErrorDomain` error is [`NSURLErrorBackgroundSessionRequiresSharedContainer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlerrorbackgroundsessionrequiressharedcontainer) according to [OSStatus](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=995), so it sounds like you'll need to set up a shared container.

Comment: Yes, my question seems dupish of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576422/nsurlsession-with-share-extension-returns-995-on-osx. at least setting sharedContainerIdentifier to one of the appgroup s supported fixes this (which unfortunately had to be fixed in swiftlydropbox, and fixing it unveiled other bugs). Not sure what's the best way to post this patch given that a portion of it is my app group dependent.