# Alamofire background upload fails

Tags: ios, swift, background, upload, alamofire

I have a working Alamofire upload request using the following:

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    ...
}
```

Now I want the request to be launched in background, as it's embedded in a Share extension.

Looking at Alamofire page, I simply added:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com...")
let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

sessionManager.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    ...
}
```

Now when executed I instantly get:

> Operation couldn't complete. NSURLErrorDomain error -995

I can't find any reference to this error and what it means. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Press command-shift-O and then search for `NSURLError` and you'll see `-995` is `NSURLErrorBackgroundSessionRequiresSharedContainer`. Are you doing this in an extension?

Comment: Yes I do, is there anything to add? Thanks!

Comment: Go to target properties, choose "capabilities" and turn on app group. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42172748/1271826.

Comment: Ok had to specify it in the sessionManager. Now I have a "cancelled" error. Back to your 1st comment, I don't see the error code numbers when I open NSURLError.

Comment: In Xcode 9 you will see the numbers. In Xcode 8 you have to open an Objective-C file before you hit command-shift-O (create a blank Objective-C project if you want).

Comment: Ok solved my issues. Please make an official answer with: configuration.sharedContainerIdentifier = Config.appGroupName so I can validate